# Unable to accept songs submitted to moderated group via SoundCloud API

Tags: soundcloud

I'm getting 404 when hitting url like this, (offc. with variables changed to proper values):

```
PUT https://api.soundcloud.com/groups/<group_id>/pending_tracks/<track_id>
```

Calling `DELETE` on that same URL works as expected, it rejects submission from group.
Requesting simple `GET .../pending_tracks` (no track-id at the end) works fine for me.

The tools I have used so far to test this are:

- official PHP library (by mptre),
- manually constructed cURL request,
- cURL binary on windows

I couldn't find any info in SoundCloud API docs (or on the internet) how this API method should or could be used. Any chance someone could help me with how it is supposed to be accessed properly, these are the questions:

- what is the correct url
- if there should be any, what is expected as the query data
- if there a query body and what is the format.

---

More details:

Calling `PUT /groups/44/pending_tracks/99119291` returns 404, so I've figured
out, the track ID must be supplied some other way.
By digging trough the PHP wrapper and gathering pieces of info scattered
around the internet, I've found out that some PUT requests are complemented
with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and other have XML in their body. So far I went with
postfields approach.

My curl binary config looks like this:

```
--url https://api.soundcloud.com/groups/44/pending_tracks
--cacert cacert.pem
--user-agent PHP-SoundCloud
--header "Accept: application/json"
--header "Authorization: OAuth XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
--request PUT
--data <!--read on please-->
```

The data section was tested with following strings, each time supplying as
a value track-id like this `track[id]=99119291`:

```
track
track[]
track[id]
track-id
track_id
trackid
approve
approved
approve[]
approve[tracks][]
approved[tracks][]
tracks[approve][]
tracks[approved][]
approve[tracks][][id]
approved[tracks][][id]
tracks[approve][][id]
tracks[approved][][id]
tracks[]
tracks[][id]
tracks[][track][id]
tracks[][track][][id]
group[][id]
group[approve][]
group[approve][id]
group[approve][][id]
group[approved][]
group[approved][id]
group[approved][][id]
group[track][approve]
group[track][approve][]
group[track][approved][]
group[track][approve][id]
group[track][approve][][id]
group[track][approved][][id]
group[track][id]
group[tracks][id]
group[track][][id]
group[tracks][][id]
group[tracks][]


groups[][id]
groups[approve][id]
groups[approve][][id]
groups[approved][id]
groups[approved][][id]


groups[track][approve]
groups[track][approve][]
groups[track][approved][]
groups[track][approve][id]
groups[track][approve][][id]
groups[track][approved][][id]
groups[track][id]
groups[tracks][id]
groups[track][][id]
groups[tracks][][id]
```

Needless to say, none of those worked, each time result was the same as if I was accessing API endpoint with a simple GET request.
I'm really tired of blindly poking the SoundCloud API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry for you pain with the API, I fully agree it deserves a lot more and better documentation.

Anyway, while it's unclear to me why it got implemented like this, you should be able to approve tracks by sending a `PUT` request to `api.soundcloud.com/groups/:group_id/tracks/:track_id`. I hope that helps.

Comment: Wow, that is a bit unlucky but I'm very happy that is works. Thanks to your answer now I can rain a slew of accept/reject requests to the pending list of 5000 tracks.