# Block/Ban user from SoundCloud group via API

Tags: rest, soundcloud

How does one block/ban one user from a SoundCloud group via REST API?

#### Logic:

Though not in the docs (but then again, lots of other wrong info is there), one would expect that this should work:

```
DEL api.soundecloud.com/groups/{id}/members/{member_id}
```

#### Note:

Taught by my [previous experience](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467591/unable-to-accept-songs-submited-to-moderated-group-via-soundcloud-api), I did not venture into testing any of my ideas since there is probably no way to guess how developers got it implemented, if implemented at all.

Comment: if so, try a look in the console.

Comment: Did that, found nothing special. Not sure what is there to see.